# using appsettings.json in blazor server app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am developing Blazor server app and I want to store database connection info and credentials in the configuration. From the research that I did, I know that I **MUST NOT** store credentials in appsettings.json in Blazor Webassembly app, however is it same for Blazor server app? I know that in case of blazor server-side, appsettings.json does not get exposed to the client, so is it ok to store sensitive info there? If not, where should I store the credentials and connection info? Thank you in advance.

Well, I read the microsoft documentation and some other articles, however most of them focus on blazor webassembly and not blazor server app, that is why I wanted to make sure and asked this question.

Comment: Blazor Server is a server-side ASP.NET Core application, so anything that applies to MVC or Razor Pages applies to it too.

Comment: So, as I researched, appsettings.json is relatively safe, a security risk only comes in if the server is breached, am I right?

Comment: As I said, same as any other server-side web app. Also, how the app is hosted - cloud? File storage is secure as long as there's no breach. You can use permissions and file system encryption to protect the file up to a point. In a Kubernetes cluster or Docker container, you can pass credentials as environment variables, or map to an external settings file. Nobody else can access the server, so nobody else can read them. In a cloud environment, secrets may be injected in the same way. If you need to, you can use a Key vault service to store and retrieve secrets.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry if the questions are a little basic. I am new to asp.net and web apps in general. Also, the app is hosted on IIS on windows server and yes I am aware that I can use Azure KeyVault or Environment variables. As I see appsettings.json is the easiest approach, but least secure, Azure KeyVault seems as the most secure approach. What do you suggest?

Comment: It depends. If you are building something for a client then I'd probably go with KeyVault but if it's just a hobby project and you want to take the easy route then user secrets should be ok. You can access user secrets by right clicking on your project in visual studio and selecting 'Manage User Secrets'. User secrets is sort of an extension to appsettings.json but a bit more safe.